# TypeError: element.select2 is not a function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-select2, angularjs-select2

I have used select.js for jquery, it works fine.

But, when the Select2 for angular with below versions
Select2 : https://github.com/rubenv/angular-select2
Angular : v1.4.9

Iam getting the below error

```
TypeError: element.select2 is not a function
   at link.getOptions (app.js:31163)
   at getSelection (app.js:31231)
   at link.controller.$render (app.js:31250)
   at Object.ngModelWatch (app.js:25987)
   at Scope.$digest (app.js:16229)
   at Scope.$apply (app.js:16501)
   at bootstrapApply (app.js:1822)
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/r23mjL01/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are using an obsolete library
use the ui-select:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select